# JSON to blueprint/MSON

Tags: json, swagger, apiblueprint, mson

I havent been able to find any tools for this conversion, does anyone know of any that exist.

Currently, I have JSON data from Swagger that I would like to convert to Blueprint/MSON to use with Apiary, but I am not sure if this is possible. Any recommendations would be super helpful, or suggestions for other routes to try and onboard my API to Apiary without manually writing it.

Comment: This functionality is currently being added to the Apiary library called [Fury.js](https://github.com/apiaryio/fury.js). It will be an adapter for converting from Swagger 2.0 to API Blueprint.

There are currently no docs as it's still being developed, but you can see how we're using it in the [tests](https://github.com/apiaryio/fury.js/blob/master/test/integration/adapters/swagger20-test.es6).  Will come back to give a full answer when this is ready to be used. Wanted to provide this in the mean time.

Comment: Cool! I just developed a version of my own, which basically takes the swagger output and converts it to MSON...

Comment: Luke: Is there a public repo for this? We have some of this in our library, too.

Comment: @LukeLevis can you share the tool you were talking about?

Answer (score 2):

There is one here: [MSONGenerator](https://msongenerator.herokuapp.com). Takes a while to load, but you paste your JSON and get nice MSON out of it. No source code for it as far as I can see, but I didn't look very far.

There's also [mson-to-schemas](https://github.com/madewithlove/mson-to-schemas/), an npm package. I have no experience with it.

Source: API Blueprint [tools section](https://apiblueprint.org/tools.html#parsers)